# KeyPress\Up\Down doesn't work - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, key-events

I have this code:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Fail!");
}
```

And I've set the event in the `Form` - but it simply isn't activated.
Other events like `Resize` or `MouseDown` work well, only this doesn't work.

Did someone ever experience this problem? What can I do ? [NO button works, neither characters or numerical or whatever].
Thanks, Mark!

Comment: Are there any other controls placed on the form ?  Does any of those controls have focus ?

Comment: Do you have the form in focus, when you press the key?

Comment: The form has focus. There are other cntrls [textbox,buttons,numerical up-down] - I cannot unfocus all ctrls...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dis you set the`Form1.KeyPreview = true` for more info visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

i think you have  set like this..

```
 KeyPreview property set to true
```

and try this.....

```
int _i = 0;
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) {
        label1.Text = (++_i).ToString();
    }
}
```